# Finding the solution of displaying references value instead of question mark sing in power all collection

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I am working on one task where two tables are there in data verse that is Department table and expense table bother are related to each other using look up column department ID.

following are the tables with the data
[image]

[image]

I tried to add two tables records in collection in power app

Like
Collection 1

```
ClearCollect(
col1 , ShowColumns('TBL Departments',"cr853_departmentid","cr853_departmentname")
);
```

Collection 2

```
ClearCollect(
col2, ShowColumns('TBL Expenses',"cr853_DEP_ID","cr853_expensedetail","cr853_expenseamount")
)
```

When I see the collection in Power App I can see question mark in reference column like this in expense table

[image]

So How can I see respective department ID and I also want department name in collection 2.

Can any one help me on that by providing the code solution of that?

I tried

```
ClearCollect(
    NewTable,
    AddColumns(
        'TBL Expenses',
        'Department_Name',
        LookUp('TBL Departments', 'Department ID' = 'TBL Expenses'[@'Department ID'], 'Department Name')
    )
)
```

But error is coming. I checked column names, and all this types of thing, but not working out, and also I have seen the some communities page, but not getting the exact solution.